# Mistake in Checkbox Code

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have connect the button right, so it must be a problem with the code.
When I touch in the button in the simulator there will be no X in it. And no sign else.

```
- (IBAction)SelectButton:(id)sender{
if (boxSelected == 0){
    [Checkbox setSelected:YES];
    boxSelected = 1;
} else {
    [Checkbox setSelected:NO];
    boxSelected = 0;
}
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    boxSelected = 0;
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (void)dealloc {
}
```

Comment: you make a - but you didn't answer !?

Comment: What is `Checkbox`? You are providing far too little information to get good help. Have you verified, through the debugger, that your `SelectButton` method is being called? BTW - it is common practice that method names and variable names begin with lowercase. Class names begin with uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

Are you can do something like this:

```
[checkbox setSelected: ![checkbox isSelected]];
```

?